# Task level failures are not triggered, in fact the dag level is repeated with alert TWICE

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-webserver

```
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.decorators import task, dag
from airflow.providers.ssh.operators.ssh import SSHOperator
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
import airflow
import sending_mail

# Task-level callback for sending mail on task success and failure
def on_trigger(context):
    task_instance = context.get("task_instance")
    state = task_instance.state
    task_id = task_instance.task_id
    dag_id = task_instance.dag_id
    run_id = task_instance.run_id
    start_date = task_instance.start_date
    end_date = task_instance.end_date
    log_url = task_instance.log_url

    SUBJECT = f"Airflow {state.upper()} alert for Task {task_id} in DAG {dag_id}"
    MESSAGE = f"""
        <b>STATE:</b> {state} <BR>
        <b>DAG:</b> {dag_id} <BR>
        <b>RUN ID:</b> {run_id} <BR>
        <b>TASK:</b> {task_id} <BR>
        <b>START TIME:</b> {start_date} <BR>
        <b>END TIME:</b> {end_date} <BR>
        <b>LOG URL:</b> {log_url} <BR>
    """
    sending_mail.sending(MESSAGE, SUBJECT)

# on_success_dag definition for overall DAG, which would be called post all tasks are completed only when all are successful
def on_success_dag(context):
    dag = context.get("task_instance").dag_id
    SUBJECT = "Airflow success alert for DAG - " + dag
    MESSAGE = """
        <b>SUCCESSFULLY COMPLETED THE DAG:</b> {dag} <BR>
        <b>DURATION:</b> {time} <BR>
        <b>RUN ID:</b> {run_id} <BR>
        """.format(
            dag=context.get("task_instance").dag_id,
            time=context.get("task_instance").duration,
            run_id=context["dag_run"].run_id,
        )
    sending_mail.sending(MESSAGE, SUBJECT)

# on_failure_dag definition for overall DAG, which would be called post all tasks are completed only EVEN any 1 of tasks failure
def on_failure_dag(context):
    dag = context.get("task_instance").dag_id
    SUBJECT = "Airflow failure alert for DAG - " + dag

    failed_task_ids = []
    dag_run = context.get("dag_run")
    for task in dag_run.get_task_instances(state="failed"):
        failed_task_ids.append(task.task_id)

    MESSAGE = """
        <b>FAILURE OF THE DAG:</b> {dag} <BR>
        <b>DURATION:</b> {time} <BR>
        <b>FOLLOWING TASK/s FAILED IN THE DAG:</b> {failed_task_ids} <BR>
        <b>EXECUTION DATE:</b> {execution_date} <BR>
        <b>LOG URL:</b> {log_url} <BR>
    """.format(
        dag=dag,
        time=context.get("task_instance").duration,
        failed_task_ids=failed_task_ids,
        execution_date=context["execution_date"],
        log_url=context.get("task_instance"),
    )
    sending_mail.sending(MESSAGE, SUBJECT)

# Default DAG syntax and its arguments
with DAG(
    dag_id="dag_id_name",
    schedule_interval="0 * * * *",
    max_active_runs=1,
    default_args={
        "start_date": datetime(2023, 6, 24),
        "retries": 1,
        "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=5),
        "catchup": False,
    },
    on_success_callback=on_success_dag,
    on_failure_callback=on_failure_dag,
    render_template_as_native_obj=True,
    tags=["production"],
) as dag:

# Executes the container
task1 = SSHOperator(
task_id="oprt1", 
ssh_conn_id='connection1', 
command='sh -x script.sh ', 
dag=dag,
on_success_callback=on_trigger,
on_failure_callback=on_trigger,
)

task1
```

As per the above code there should be FAILURE or SUCCESS at TASK_LEVEL and even DAG_LEVEL. However the success level works very well, but when it comes to the failed level the dag_level is triggered TWICE, but the task_levels is not triggered at all for the failed level

```
As even tried setting this within dag definition like this, but same result
 # Default DAG syntax and its arguments
    with DAG(
        dag_id="dag_id_name",
        schedule_interval="0 * * * *",
        max_active_runs=1,
        default_args={
            "start_date": datetime(2023, 6, 24),
            "retries": 1,
            "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=5),
            "on_failure_callback": on_trigger,
            "on_success_callback": on_trigger,
            "catchup": False,
        },
        on_success_callback=on_success_dag,
        on_failure_callback=on_failure_dag,
        render_template_as_native_obj=True,
        tags=["production"],
    ) as dag:
```

How can I get the alerts for even task level and dag level even for the failure